# consumir dos JSON en un servicio de angular

Tags: angular, json

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar angular y no encuentro como hacer para consumir **dos (o más) archivos JSON en un solo servicio**.
el codigo del servicio es el siguiente:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResumeService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getData():Observable<any> { 
    return this.http.get('../../assets/data/resumeData.json');
  }
}
```

Dentro de la linea

**return this.http.get('../../assets/data/resumeData.json');**

es donde obtengo la URL del archivo JSON, pero no se como hacer para retornar mas de uno. Sé que deberia poner la direccion en una variable, pero de igual manera no se como hacer para inyectar mas de un archivo

Comment: Puedes crear otra función que lea el otro json y desde el componente donde inyectas el servicio para obtener los datos, realizas una llamada a cada función

Comment: duplique `getData():Observable<any>` le cambie de nombre y le puse la url del otro Json. asi trae los datos que necesito, ahora tengo que poder utilizarlos en el html. Gracias!